# how to make grid footer lines to none in gridview

Tags: asp.net

i want to disable Footer gridlines in gridview.How can we do this

Answer (score 0):

use `<FooterStyle CssClass="FooterStyle" />` on your grid view and add `.FooterStyle{border:0;}` in your css